# Network disconnected. You are offline now

Tags: networking

My internet access doesn't work any more and I constantly get the message `Network disconnected. You are offline now.` every 3 seconds.

This might (or might not) relate to my printer where I accidentally pressed a kind of network button.

I didn't find any useful info in the official Ubuntu documentation:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SystemAdministration

Any help, please?

Comment: Try `sudo killall NetworkManager`. NetworkManager will automatically restart and try to reconnect to the network.

Comment: When you turn off the printer and remove its power cord, does that solve the problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem when my (five year old) router was failing.  If you can connect another computer to the same router, you can see if the same problem occurs; if it does, it's most likely a failing router.  Given the cost of new routers (under $20 for generic with 4 wire ports plus uplink and b/g/n wifi) it's easy enough to replace it if you suspect that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I booted a Non-Ubuntu LiveCD and the same error message came up. So I'm sure it is the hardware.

Thanks for both answer/comment so far. I will buy a new router.